# Ошибка "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'into' (T_STRING)" при попытке вставки данных в базу

Tags: mysqli, php7

```html
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "rustem", "russia", "new_db");

if (!$link) {
    echo "Ошибка: Невозможно установить соединение с MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Код ошибки errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Текст ошибки error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

echo "Соединение с MySQL установлено!" . PHP_EOL;
echo "Информация о сервере: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . PHP_EOL;

$query =  "INSERT INTO 'users' (first_name, last_name, email, facebook) VALUES('{$first_name}', '{$last_name}', '{$email}', '{$facebook}');";

mysqli_query ($link, $query);


mysqli_close($link);
```

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'into' (T_STRING) in C:\server\data\htdocs\php\un.php on line 15

при правке на $query = "INSERT INTO 'users' (first_name, last_name, email, facebook) VALUES('first_name1', 'last_name2', 'email2', 'facebook2');";
без ошибок но данные не заносятся в существующий БД

Comment: версия пхп тут роли не играет. в чем вопрос?

Comment: Как написать типа занести в базу данных mysql на mysqli некие данные и прочесть?

Comment: Я пробовал inserto не получается

Comment: вы ознакомьтесь с документацией по mysql сначала и вообще по базам данных

Comment: Я читал в phpmyadmin у меня все получается.

Comment: $query = insert into 'users' values ('first_name1','last_name1','email1','facebook1S');

mysqli_query ($link, $query);

Comment: Но когда я пишу вот так в браузере выскакивает ошибка синтаксиса на той линии которой она находится

Comment: вы можете  нажать [edit] у вопроса, что бы отредактировать его и вставить недостающий SQL код

Comment: Ошибку синтаксиса тоже приведите в вопросе.

Comment: @teran, все уже написано https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/667673/mysqli-php-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%8b-php-7-mysql-5-7-18 а это дубликат того вопроса.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Mysqli PHP не могу записать ни прочесть данные с базы. PHP 7 MySql 5.7.18](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/667673/mysqli-php-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%8b-php-7-mysql-5-7-18)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да ни разу не дубликат. Ну да, автор не нашел кнопку редактирования - но это же не повод хороший вопрос объявлять дубликатом плохого?

Comment: @Рустемчик прошу обратить внимание - ни одного ответа вам еще не давали. Не путайте ответы и комментарии.

Comment: @PavelMayorov вы посмотрите в каком виде был вопрос задан в [первой редакции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/667710/1), когда я писал этот коммент, тогда и вопрос может отпадет сам собой.

Comment: @PavelMayorov аналогично ^^^ .. но и ничто не мешает его закрыть, а правки внести в предыдущий. Или наоборот